# How do I save multiple values of record in PHP to enter in database

Tags: php

This is the code that I use to retrieve data from database for taking attendance.

```
<?php 
    while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td> 
        <input type='text' name='enrol' value='$row4[enrolment_no]' />
        <div class='make-switch switch-small'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='attendance' />
        </div> 
        </td>
        <td> 
        <div class='checkbox'>
        <label>
        <input class='uniform' type='checkbox'  name='event'/>
        </label>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>$row4[roll_no]</td>
        <td>$row4[stud_fname] $row4[stud_lname]</td>
        </tr>   ";
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you tried? do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

### Change your Code in loop like this

```
    <?php 
    while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
  echo "
        <tr>
            <td> 
            <input type='text' name='enrol' value='".$row4['enrolment_no']."' />
                    <div class='make-switch switch-small'>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='attendance' />
                    </div> 
            </td>
            <td> 
                    <div class='checkbox'>
                        <label>
                            <input class='uniform' type='checkbox'  name='event'/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td>".$row4['roll_no']."</td>
            <td>".$row4['stud_fname']."".$row4['stud_lname']."</td></tr>";

    }
?>
```